# How to draw a horizontal line over bar columns in Chart.js that's started from X axis?

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, chart.js, linechart

I have a bar type chart in chart.js with some columns and i want to draw a straight horizontal line at some point to the chart overt the bar columns.
I've tried to add a simple line type chart with equal point, but the problem is, the line doesn't start from X axis. The points are centered because of bar chart categories, but i want the line to be started from X axis.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by adding a second hidden X axis and i use that for the line chart.